# Volatile variables does not work as expected

Tags: java, volatile

I thought that if I have 2 volatile variables `i`, `i1` then if I set for example:

```
i = 2;
i = 3;
i1 = 5;
```

So another thread will never find that `i1 == 5` but `i == 2`, but try the below code and see that sometimes it does not work as expected:

```java
public class Main {
    private static volatile int i = 0;
    private static volatile int i1 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(Main::writerThread);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(Main::readerThread);
        t.start();
        t1.start();
        t.join();
        t1.join();
    }

    public static void writerThread() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            i = j;
            i1 = j;
        }
    }

    public static void readerThread() {
        int myI, myI1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++) {
            myI = i;
            myI1 = i1;
            if (myI1 > myI) {
                System.out.println(myI + " < " + myI1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`myI` should never be `< myI1`, but sometimes it is. For example i got: `711 < 712`.

Comment: One of the neat things about modern processors is they can do multiple small operations at the same time in a single core. Since you made them volatile, it probably decided that the order at which they are assigned does not matter so long as the end result is achieved before the end of the processor clock cycle. If ordering of operations is important, you can use an atomic type.

Answer (score 4):

A write to a single `volatile` variables is atomic.  But a sequence of writes to two or more `volatile` variables is NOT atomic.

Here is an execution trace that would result in the output "711 < 712".

```
writer:  j -> 711
writer:  i -> 711
writer:  i1 -> 711
reader:  read i (711) ; 711 -> myI
writer:  j -> 712
writer:  i -> 712
writer:  i1 -> 712
reader:  read i1 (712) ; 712 -> myI1
reader:  myI1 (712) > myI (711) == true
```

QED

<sup>(The `j` in the above is the writer's variable.  The value of the reader's `j` has no bearing on the output.)</sup>

In short, your program *as written* does not guarantee that `myI` is never less than `myI1`.